# script to remove primary key from multiple tables of a database in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, primary-key

I have many tables in my database and each table has primary key, unique key and auto-increment in it. I want to remove all three of these. How i can do it in a script without doing it manually for each table in the database. Is there any automate script for droping all these in all the tables of a database at once.

(From Comment)

```
CREATE TABLE emp3 (
    id int NOT NULL, 
    name varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    UNIQUE KEY c_unique (name)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: Simply perform `CREATE TABLE new_table SELECT * FROM old_table` - new tables won't contain indices and AI attributes.

Comment: @Akina - But then you need to put some PK back on, plus any useful indexes.

Comment: The answer to your question is no, there is no automated script for dropping all of these in all tables at once. ALTER TABLE acts on one table at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ENGINE=InnoDB`, then you really need to have a `PRIMARY KEY` on each table.

If you have `JOINs` between tables, you need to avoid dropping the column you are `JOINing` on.

Are the PK, unique key and AI column named consistently across the tables?

Please show us an example `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can tailor the answer to your need.

The Answer will *include* something like

```
SELECT
    CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ", table_name, "... ;")
    FROM information_schema
    WHERE table_schema = 'db_name';
```

Plus instructions on how to either use the "mysql" commandline tool or a stored proc to execute the commands created.

Comment: SELECT
    CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ", table_name, "... ;")
    FROM information_schema
    WHERE table_schema = '...';  what will be the table_schema in where condition

Comment: create table emp3 (id int primary key auto_increment, name varchar(30), constraint c_unique unique (name));     this is the sample am using for create table

Comment: @shubhijain - "table schema" is a synonym for "DATABASE".

Comment: 'emp3', 'CREATE TABLE `emp3` (\n  `id` int NOT NULL,\n  `name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,\n  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),\n  UNIQUE KEY `c_unique` (`name`)\n) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'
this is what show create table gives. Please help me tailor the answer according to this

Comment: @shubhijain - That looks good, except that `AUTO_INCREMENT` is missing.

Comment: create table emp3 (id int primary key auto_increment, name varchar(30), constraint c_unique unique (name));    here is the one with auto increment. I habe multiple tables like this in my db so how i can script it to drop these out from my tables

Comment: @shubhijain - Run my select (after filling in some details.  See what it generates -- a bunch of ALTER datatements.  Then use the mysql commandline tool to perform them (or some UI).